# Access object from array in PHP - can't print object values?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
// Search users tweets
$tweets = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", ["screen_name" => "youtube"]);
print_r($tweets);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        [created_at] => Wed Oct 11 21:37:05 +0000 2017
        [id] => 918228989541482496
        [id_str] => 918228989541482496
        .........
```

A array with a bunch of objects in it, i'm trying to access all the [id] variables in the output.

I've tried:

```
foreach ($arrayOfObjs as $key => $0) {
echo $object->id;
}
```

and

```
echo $array[0]->id;
```

And a bunch of other solutions on this site but can't get anything to display anything.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the class?, is laravel the one you are using it?, also check if you can access this property like `$array[0]['id']`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `$tweets[0]->id`?

Comment: `$0` is not a valid PHP variable name

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by class? im new to this.

Comment: sure @OluwafemiSule, he is only putting an example, replace tweets in the example below for array, the problem is to access the fields of the object

Comment: `foreach ($tweets as $tweet) echo $tweet->id;`

Comment: `foreach ($tweets as $tweet) { echo $tweet->id; }`

Comment: @Phil haha. snap :)

Comment: Make sure you can see any potential errors in your code while developing. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of your PHP script

Comment: awesome Phil, that worked! thanks! I now have a long list of numbers which I presume I can get onto individual lines with a new line function.

Comment: @bretanac93 "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
    echo $tweet->id;
}
```

Comment: What is `$arrayOfObjs`? OP stores the array of objects into `$tweets`

Comment: OP gave a $tweets example and an $arrayOfObjs example

Comment: OP also used invalid and non-existent variables. Also, this was also solved in the comments 8 minutes prior to your answer